# Prevent Command-T from changing directories

Tags: vim, macvim

My problem is that Command-T changes the current directory when opening a file. How do I prevent this?

I've followed the instructions here: [Prevent vim from changing directories when opening files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621401/prevent-vim-from-changing-directories-when-opening-files) but `setting noautochdir` doesn't seem to have any effect.

If I just open a file like this `:e folder/folder/file.ext` vim doesn't change pwd, but when I use Command-T to open a file it changes the current directory.

Comment: Have you looked through the Command-T sources to see if it does `cd` anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prevent change directory I use vim-rooter plugin. https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter. It works fine with Command-T and Nerdtree.